# Parsing nested JSON via Google Scripts

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, jsonparser

I've been struggling to try to find a way online to parse JSON output from an API request successfully.

I'm looking to parse the "ResultData" section of the following API JSON Example Output:

{"url":"http://elasticbeanstalk.com/api/results/69/","id":69,"user":3,"inputdata":{"Q1":"Response1","Q2":"Response2","Q3":"Response3","Q4":"Response4","Q5":"Response5"},"ResultData":"{\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}\n {\"index\":1551,\"ID\":5246,\"Attribute1\":\"Output1\",\"Attribute2\":\"Output2",\"Attribute3\":16,\"Attribute4\":62.9433099,\"Attribute5\":\"www.google.com.au\"}"}

Want the following values for each row exported into google sheets:

index   ID  Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3  Attribute4  Attribute5

Any ideas? Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just split the "ResultData" string using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the newline character (\n) as the delimiter and then [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the elements of the resulting array.

Comment: @prks21 Glad I could help. However, there are a few redundancies in your code. You should consider optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Parsed it, then split it, then looped through the individual results data lines using the parseJSON function.

```
var OutputData = JSON.parse(response).ResultData;
OutputData = OutputData.split('\n');

// run this look while the variable i is less than 5 and increment i by 1 each time 
the end of the loop is reached
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
var ResultData = JSON.parse(OutputData[i]);
parseJSON(i,ResultData);
}

}

function parseJSON(result, myObject) {
// define an array of all the object keys

var headerRow = Object.keys(myObject);

// define an array of all the object values
var row = headerRow.map(function(key){ return myObject[key]});

// define the contents of the range
var contents = [
 headerRow,
 row
];

var contents1 = [
 row
];

// select the range and set its values
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var rng = ss.getSheetByName("Results").getRange(1, 1, contents.length, headerRow.length )
var rng1 = ss.getSheetByName("Results").getRange(result+2, 1, 1, headerRow.length )

   if (result == 0 ) {
        rng.setValues(contents)
    }
    else {
        rng1.setValues(contents1)
    }

}
```